# How to set up an Azure Function that listens only to HTTP POST using python model v2?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm migrating my Azure Function App from the v1 to [v2 Python Programming Model](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-compute-blog/azure-functions-v2-python-programming-model-is-generally/ba-p/3827474).  The one thing I can't figure out is how to have my HTTP-triggered function to listen *only* to POST requests.  Meaning it should not accept GET requests.

In the v1 model, you would specify the exhaustive list of HTTP `"methods"` in function.json:

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["post"]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

What's the equivalent in the v2 model?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a tuple of HTTP methods as a property on the `@app.route` decorator:

```
@app.route(route="migrate-datasets", methods=("POST",))
def migrate(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    pass
```

Documentation for this decorator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python#decorators